# sending a simple email with python3

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email on python3.  I am forwarding the email to a relay server. I have followed several tutorials online and all give me the same error message. Not sure how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testEmail.py", line 17, in <module>
    msg['Subject'] = "Test mail"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import smtplib

port = 25
msg = "This is test mail"

msg['Subject'] = "Test mail"
msg['From'] = 'test@test.com'
msg['To'] = 'my-name@test2.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP('10.1.2.3', port)
s.send_messsage(msg)
s.quit()
print("Successfully sent email")
```

Comment: You're treating `msg` like it is a `dict` or some other kind of object like that, but you're initializing it with a string. You've followed your tutorials/examples/documentation incorrectly.

Comment: Just like @RandomDavis said `msg = dict()` or `msg = {}` is not the same as `msg = ""` (this is a string, can't have key/value mapping).

Answer (score 0):

According to all the examples in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html), `msg` needs to be an `EmailMessage`.

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("This is test mail")
msg['Subject'] = "Test mail"
...
```

It's good to just read the basic, official documentation and examples when using a module so you don't miss basic stuff like this.